# Nginx Node Proxypass Result to Variable

Tags: nginx, rewrite, node.js, ngx-http-rewrite-module

I want create some rewrite with nginx (5 million links), I read nginx have the option to save it in a map file but need ages to reload + ram usage when I do it this way.

My Idea was now `User -> Nginx -> Node(which gives the link) -> Save the link in a Variable of nginx -> Nginx rewrite to the file`

I tryt to supply file direct over node with express but have already 50% usage with 300 connections.

Is this posible or im on the completly wrong way?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can have the Node server return the link as an `X-Accel-Redirect` header and Nginx will rewrite the request to whatever link your backend server gives it.

Comment: seems nice, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23904521/nginx-x-accel-redirect-not-working-with-node-js have asked the same things, nice to know when u know what u have looking for